Display route title in a header component in Angular, always returns undefined
I have a seemingly simple problem. I have a header component where I want to display the title of the currently active route. For this I inject the ActivatedRoute into the header component and try to display the route title like this:
export class HeaderComponent {
    public title$;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.title$ = route.title;
    }
}

and the html of the component
<header>
    <h1>My Website - {{ title$ | async }}</h1>
</header>

Somehow this does not work. But I can see that the title I defined in the different routes update the browser windows title.

Your header component seem to be used in your ShellComponent and I suppose your routing config feels like looks like this:
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',  
    component: ShellComponent, // <-- Header component is used here
    children: [  // might be load children
       { path: 'route1', title: 'My title', component: ...}, // <-- title is here
       ...
    ] 
  }
]

So if this is correct then you can see that Header component is located in routing/injector/component tree above the routes with titles defined.
When you inject ActivatedRoute in your HeaderComponent you will get your route instance of this wrapper
{
    path: '',  
    component: ShellComponent,

it doesn't have title so you will get it undefined.
What you can do is if you dont have multi router-outlet structure then you can manually get deep into the route tree to get your most child route. Something like this
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  get leaf(): ActivatedRoute {
    let leaf = this.route;
    while (leaf.firstChild) {
      leaf = leaf.firstChild;
    }
    return leaf;
  }

and in template do
{{leaf.title | async}}


You should be careful about change detection strategy on your components.
Your get leaf() will be executed whenever change detection comes to this component but if you have OnPush you will have to mark you component for check when route changes manually. You can listen to router.events for example and whenever there is NavigationEnd event do markForCheck to get it updated.
Or you can do a mixed version to make it work with OnPush
  #route = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  #router = inject(Router);

  title$ = this.#router.events.pipe(
    filter((evt) => evt instanceof NavigationEnd),
    startWith(null),
    switchMap(() => this.leaf.title)
  );

  get leaf(): ActivatedRoute {
    let leaf = this.#route;
    while (leaf.firstChild) {
      leaf = leaf.firstChild;
    }
    return leaf;
  }

and use in template
{{title$ | async}}

So final solution depends on your change detection strategy setup
Working result: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ca3d4z?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Ah, this makes sense. The solution is a bit more complicated then I would have liked but it works great.
